# Do sharing settings apply for records inserted in test classes?

Tags: apex, sharing, unit-test

I've inserted records in test classes. When I try to update the inserted record by using `System.runAs(curUser)`, I get the following error INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY. 
I guess it's because the inserted record is not shared with curUser. 

So, do sharing settings apply for records inserted in test classes?

Is there any other reason for this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use System.RunAs() the sharing settings and the permissions of the user apply even in test method

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/apex_runas.htm

The above document link confirms the same

Update:

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY. This is because you dont have access to the records .One solution will be to create the records in test class using the same user as you want to test so that the user has access to the record .

Comment: Thank you mohit! I didn't RTFM. But that doesn't explain the error.

Comment: Thanks mohit. I was creating User records in test class and then using it in System.runAs(). I've queried a user record and then used System.runAs(), the error disappeared.